# Why are web workers not allowed to modify the dom

Tags: multithreading, html, web-worker

I know `web workers` work as a separate thread than the `UI thread` but i dont understand why they are not allowed to modify the `DOM`. I mean that you can allow inter thread communication and keep the `DOM` data in a shared space and have the `web workers` thread modify the `DOM`. Why is this not allowed in browsers?

Comment: It happens on almost every programming language that does GUI: only the main thread can call GUI functions (eg: Android, Delphi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the DOM is not threadsafe, and JavaScript does not expose a thread API.

---

See also:

- [Is JavaScript multithreaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663125/is-javascript-multithreaded)
- [Thread Safety in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253586/thread-safety-in-javascript)
- [Using web workers - About thread safety](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers#About_thread_safety)

Comment: _"A piece of code is thread-safe if it can be safely invoked by multiple threads at the same time."_ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Comment: can you tell me some references where i can read more about thread safety of DOM? thanks

Comment: It's not thread safe, and was never intended to be, since ***JavaScript does not have any concept of a thread*** or other concurrent/parallel constructs. That's it.