# Accessing the same variable from a function and an event handler

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a variable that can be modified by two functions: one is invoked periodically via `setTimeout` and the other is an event handler:

```
var a = [];
function foo()
{
   var x = a.pop();
   // do something with x...
   setTimeout(function(){ foo(); }, 1);
}
//...
someElement.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){ a.push("some value"); }, true);
```

Is this code safe? Do the event listener and `foo` run in the same thread or in different threads? If they run in different threads, does the javascript runtime have to guarantee that access to `a` is synchronized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is always single threaded in browsers. You will have no problems with your event listener.

I will refer you to [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2253628/103959) by user [Jonathon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203600/jonathon)

Comment: Why refer and not close? Seems to be a duplicate to me.