# jQuery $.when() with variable arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I want to send [1, n) AJAX-requests to the server and after all have returned a result a modal dialog should be closed. `$.when(a(), b(), c())` would be perfect, but I don't know how to pass the variable count of functions to `$.when` as parameter. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: related: [How do you work with an array of jQuery Deferreds?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4878887/1048572)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Call the functions and add their return values to an array. Then call `$.when` passing the array as argument like so:

```
$.when.apply($, array)
```

See [`Function.prototype.apply` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more information and [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647527/jquery-deferred-do-i-need-pipes-or-chains-to-achieve-this-pattern/6648219#6648219) for an extended example.

Comment: Sometimes it's just time to knock one's head against the table... JS is too beautiful to get all of it's beauty – .apply() is one of it! Thanks a lot for the "Denkanstoß" ;-)