# How do I pass in a dynamic list of XHRRequests in jQuery's when() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery's when() and pass in a dynamic list of XHRRequests, but apparently when() does not support an array as its parameter.

How would I go about doing this?

*I would really appreciate any help, thanks!*

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery $.when() with variable arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011652/jquery-when-with-variable-arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key function here is [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```
$.when.apply(null, arrayXHR).done(function(response1, response2, ....){ 
    console.log(response1, response2 ...);
});
```

Comment: Any reason why you do not directly pass `callback` to `.done`: `$.when.apply(null, arrayXHR).done(callback)`? Or even better, return the promise to allow the calling code to attach the callbacks: `return $.when.apply($.when, arrayXHR);`.