# Using jquery deferred to sync animation and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadein, deferred

I'm trying to get my head around the whole `deferred` concept and I'm trying to use it to synchronize a `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` animation together with an Ajax call.

Basically I'm switching content on page doing:

1. Fetch content with ajax
2. On response FadeOut
3. Replace content
4. FadeIn

However, If i understand `deferred`s right I might be able to do something like this:

1. fadeOut, and at the same time initialize Fetch content with ajax
2. When both the fadeOut and the Fetch content are complete: Change content
3. FadeIn

Some code of the original solution:

```
$.get(url, function(page) {
    $('#content').fadeTo(100, 0, 'linear', function() {
        $(this).html(page.text).fadeTo(400, 1, 'linear');
    });
}
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var deferred1 = $.get(url);
var deferred2 = $('#content').fadeTo(100, 0, 'linear').promise();

$.when(deferred1, deferred2).done(function() {
    $('#content').html(page.text).fadeTo(400, 1, 'linear');
});
```

I just can't really get clear on how to use it. And should i use done or then? Should I use pipe in a clever way? Do I need `promise`?

What would be the more 'standardized' way to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `$.when` (I know, funny sentence ;)), then the values with which the promises are resolved are passed as arguments to the callback functions. I.e. in your `done` callback, the first argument refers to the resolved value of `deferred1` and the second argument to `deferred2` (whatever that is).

Now, when an Ajax success callback is called, it gets passed three arguments:

- the response
- the status text
- the `jqXHR` object

You are only interested in the first.

So with this, your setup should be:

```
var promise1 = $.get(url);
var promise2 = $('#content').fadeTo(100, 0, 'linear').promise();

$.when(promise1, promise2).done(function(ajax_success) {
    $('#content').html(ajax_success[0]).fadeTo(400, 1, 'linear');
});
```

Also have a look at the [`$.when` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

---

> Do I need `promise`?

No. It looks like `$.when` calls `.promise` internally when you pass a jQuery collection. But in other cases you would have to, so it makes sense to do this here as well, for consistency (thanks [Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak)).

> And should i ... ? Should I ...? What would be ...?

There is no standard solution for this kind of problems. Promises are incredibly flexible and there are so many ways to use. I *think* they are not around long enough in JavaScript for standard patterns to emerge. Find/create something that makes sense to you and be consistent within your application.

The only thing I would recommend to do if you have multiple promises is put them in an array: [jQuery $.when() with variable arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8011652/218196).

Comment: are you sure he doesn't need `.promise()` - AIUI a jQuery object doesn't automatically implement the promise interface to indicate animation completion, you have to call `$(...).promise()` to get the desired promise.

Comment: @Alnitak: Afaik it does. Unless it was changed recently. *edit:* Still works: http://jsfiddle.net/y5Fk7/.

Comment: not that I know of, it's been that way since animation started supporting deferred in 1.6.  See `http://api.jquery.com/promise/` vs the `deferred.promise()` function.  Calling `.promise` on a deferred just ensures you only get a (stripped back) object that only implements the promise interface, but calling `.promise` on a jQuery object is necessary to actually create the dynamic promise that will watch that element's animation queue.

Comment: But you see in the third example how `.promise` is not called? Maybe `$.when` calls `.promise` internally when a jQuery collection is passed.

Comment: Yes, that's my theory too - I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Updated my answer and will update again if you find something more specific.

Comment: It looks like `$.when()` might call `obj.promise()` on any object passed that has such a method, and jQuery objects do have it.  My general advice would be to explicitly ask for the `.promise()` in case it's being used by a method other than `$.when()`.

Comment: It seems to work with multiple objects as well (http://jsfiddle.net/y5Fk7/1/). Anyways, I updated my answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot guys, it seems promise() is not needed, and I can change .done to .then and that fiddle still seems to work. .then seems like a more flexible version of .done in the way that you can specify fail callbacks and progress callbacks

Comment: Just a quick one, Why does Promise1 not call .promise()?

Comment: @Liam: All jQuery Ajax methods return a `jqXHR` object which already implements the promise interface.

Comment: All jQuery Ajax methods **except `.load()`** return a jqXHR object. [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) returns jQuery for standard chaining.