# How to call a function after multiple events are all triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically I would like something like this (not work now definitely).
Can I use events to make the `res.send()` happen after all `client.get()` finished?

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var response = {};
var ids = [...];

for (id in ids) {
  this.client.get(id1, function(err, obj) {
    if (!err) {
      response[id.toString()] = obj;
    }
  });
}

res.send({
  response
});
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011652/jquery-when-with-variable-arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use **[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)**, *The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.*

```js
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var response = {};
var ids = [...];
var promiseArr = [];
for (id in ids) {
  var prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    this.client.get(id1, function(err, obj) {
      if (!err) {
        response[id.toString()] = obj;
        resolve();
      }
    });
  })
  promiseArr.push(prom);
}
Promise.all(promiseArr).then(function() {
  res.send({
    response: response
  });
})
```

**Note:** As commented by [*timster*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3317022/timster), Consider browser support while using `Promise object`, [**Polyfill**](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) will help!

Comment: @xgwang, _Glad to help!_

Comment: Good tip, but MSIE (up to 11) doesn't support the Promise object.