# I usually wait for a collection of asynchronous events to finish using a setInterval poller. Is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple ajax calls inside a each() function.. then do something once ALL of them are finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726046/multiple-ajax-calls-inside-a-each-function-then-do-something-once-all-of-the)

Consider the following function:

```
function suggestSong(songs){
    console.log("Suggesting song from songs:", songs);
    var self = this;
    var totalRelatedVideos = [];
    var count = 0;

    $.each(songs, function(){
        count++;
        self.getRelatedVideos(this.videoId, function(relatedVideos){
            count--;
            totalRelatedVideos = totalRelatedVideos.concat(relatedVideos);
        });
    });

    var maxWaitTime = 1000; 
    var waitTime = 200;
    var elapsedTime = 0;
    var waitInterval = setInterval(function(){
        elapsedTime += waitTime;
        if(count == 0 || elapsedTime >= maxWaitTime){
            clearInterval(waitInterval);
            console.log("I found related videos: " + totalRelatedVideos.length);
        }
    }, waitTime );
};
```

This is how I currently implement waiting for a collection of asynchronous events to finish before executing another piece of code. There's a lot of code to do very little, though. I was wondering if there's a less obtuse way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Yes, you can use deferred objects (http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Have a look at these questions for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3405218/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8726046/218196.

Comment: What is the code for getRelatedVideos?